# wp_schedule_event não está funcionando

Tags: php, wordpress

Tenho a seguinte função criada no meu **functions.php**.  Estou alterando o tema para agendar, e eu consigo ver que está agendado pela função do `next_schedule`.

```
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'prefix_setup_schedule' ); 

function prefix_setup_schedule() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'sendemail' ) ) {
        $timeschedule = strtotime(date("Y-m-d 18:00:00"));
        wp_schedule_event( $timeschedule, 'daily', 'sendemail');
    }
}

function sendemail()
{
    update_option('envioemail','feito');
}
```

Porém, esse código não está sendo executado, alguém tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira, primeiro o  `wp_schedule_event` ficou assim:

```
wp_schedule_event( $timeschedule, 'daily', 'my_daily_event');
```

Depois criei uma action assim:

```
add_action( 'my_daily_event',  'sendemail' );
```

e a função ficou normal, assim o meu problema foi resolvido.

<sub><sub>*Resposta baseada em [comentário do autor da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13187/wp-schedule-event-nao-esta-funcionando/13421#comment23828_13187).*</sub></sub>

Comment: Caio, se quiser publicar uma resposta em seu próprio nome, me avise e removo esta.